# HTTP + HTTPS + www + non-www Apache config

Tags: apache, http, https, virtualhost, no-www

In my Apache configuration, everything is redirected to HTTPS (which is good). But both `https://www.example.com` and `https://example.com` still exist.

**Question: how to have only `https://www.example.com` and not the non-www?**

Should I use a `301 Redirection` or another technique?

How should such a configuration be changed:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
  DocumentRoot /home/www/example
  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to change the current virtual host `ServerName www.example.com` and add a new Virtual Host for the non-www

`<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect 301 / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: Yes but this would break current links: example: `https://example.com/article1` will be redirected to `https://www.example.com/`, or am I wrong?

Comment: @basj no I believe the path is maintained.

Comment: Also, it doesn't work, an argument is missing: `Redirect 301 <argumentmissinghere> https://www.example.com/`

Comment: i've updated the answer - i missed the / ... also confirmed on the the path being maintained `https://example.com/about` will redirect to `https://www.example.com/about` - make sure you have the trailing slash otherwise the redirect with go to `https://www.example.comabout`

Answer (score 1):

[Relymcd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50709160/1422096) solved the problem, but it also needs the certificate lines to be present (if not it will fail):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect 301 / https://www.example.com/
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```